# Global scope for react query?

Tags: react-query

In most apps there is the need to scope cached queries by default. Let's say you allow users to use multiple accounts. You'd probably want to scope each and every query to the account the user uses.

If queries are not scoped by default, we have to pass the `accountId` to every invocation of `useQuery` like so: `useQuery([accountId, ...])`.

I'd love to know if `queryFn` can be bound to a global key like this.

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient} defaultKey={[accountId]}>{...children...}</QueryClientProvider>
```

Comment: Maybe you could just provide separate QueryClient for each accountId?

Comment: There is also this option:
https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/2814

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think switching out the entire `queryCache` would probably be the last resort here. It would be great it that could be avoided.